# Strange behaviour of C++ class in Python with SWIG

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a class in C++ with two methods (a part of a large project). The methods do a very similar job: the first one normalizes a vector and returns it, while the second returns a normalized vector without altering the original one.

`vector3.h` :

```
class Vector3
{
public:
  Vector3(double a = 0.0, double b = 0.0, double c = 0.0) 
      : x(a), y(b), z(c) {}
  Vector3(const Vector3& other) : x(other.x), y(other.y), z(other.z) {}
  double length() const { return sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z); }
  Vector3& normalize()
  {
    float_type n = length();
    n = float_type(1.0) / ( n ? n : 1.0 );
    this->x *= n;
    this->y *= n;
    this->z *= n;
    return *this;
  }
  Vector3 normalized() const
  {
    Vector3 v(*this);
    v.normalize();
    return v;
  }
  std::string toString()
  {
    std::ostringstream strm;
    strm << '(' << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << ')' ;
    return strm.str();
  }
  Vector3 operator+(const Vector3& other) const
  {
    return Vector3(x + other.x, y + other.y, z + other.z);
  }

private:
  double x,y,z;
};
```

I build Python bindings for this class with SWIG (via cmake).

`vector3.i` :

```
%include <stl.i>
%include <carrays.i>
%include <cpointer.i>
%module vectortest
%{
#include "vector3.h"
%}
%include "vector3.h"
```

`CMakeLists.txt` :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

add_executable("vtest" "vtest.cpp")

find_package(SWIG)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

find_package(PythonLibs)
find_package(PythonInterp)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

SET(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(SOURCE vector3.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
SWIG_ADD_MODULE(vectortest_python python vector3.i )
SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(vectortest_python ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} ${LIBS})
set_target_properties(_vectortest_python PROPERTIES PREFIX "_" OUTPUT_NAME "vectortest")

execute_process(COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print (get_python_lib())" OUTPUT_VARIABLE PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

install(TARGETS ${SWIG_MODULE_vectortest_python_REAL_NAME} DESTINATION ${PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES})
install(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/vectortest.py DESTINATION ${PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES})
```

The behavior in C++ is fine.

`vtest.cpp` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vector3.h"

int main()
{
  Vector3 v1(1,0,0);
  Vector3 v2(0,1,0);

  std::cout << (v1+v2).toString() << std::endl;
  std::cout << (v1+v2).normalized().toString() << std::endl;
  std::cout << (v1+v2).normalize().toString() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
(1, 1, 0)
(0.707107, 0.707107, 0)
(0.707107, 0.707107, 0)
```

However, it's behavior in Python is quite strange:

`vtest.py` :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from vectortest import Vector3

v1 = Vector3(1,0,0)
v2 = Vector3(0,1,0)
print( (v1+v2).toString() )
print( (v1+v2).normalized().toString() )
print( (v1+v2).normalize().toString() )
```

outputs:

```
(1, 1, 0)
(0.707107, 0.707107, 0)
(0, 0.707107, 0)
```

The second method (`normalized()`) work as expected, however the first one (`normalize()`) does not. What is causing this? Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: This is possibly being caused by the early destruction of `v1 + v2` in your swigged version

Comment: The `Vector3` objects are not `C++` Vector3` objects, but swigged wrapper objects. As @donkopotamus suggests, I believe the object is destroyed to early. Have you tried storing a vector `(v1+v2)` before calling `normalize()`?

Comment: Of course, storing `v1+v2` helps and "resolves" the issue. But as far as I can see both my C++ and Python codes are perfectly valid, so the result should be executed predictably correctly.  It's either my code is not valid, or there is a bug in SWIG, Python or GCC. The latter is hardly the case, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@donkopotamus and @JensMunk are right.
Your **code is incorrect in Python** because lifetime of the temporary variables differs.
Lifetime of the C++ temporary variable (v1+v2) is the whole sequence of the function calls in C++. Python calls made over the SWIG wrappers for each function call, i.e. over the **distinct** Python objects. For Python:

(v1+v2) - a temporary Python object (tp1 = v1 + v2) is constructed, whose lifetime differs from the sequence of calls.

(v1+v2).normalized()  - yields another temporary Python object (tp2_1);
**(v1+v2).normalize()**  - yields another temporary Python object (tp2_2) that internally refers the first temporary Python object (tp1).
The temporary Python object (tp1 = 
v1 + v2) decrements the reference counter and can be garbage collected now, **invalidating the contents** of tp2_2.

(v1+v2).normalized().toString()  - yields a temporary Python object (tp3_1) made from the valid tp2_1, tp2_1 can be garbage collected now;
(v1+v2).normalize().toString()  - yields a temporary Python object (tp3_2) from the possibly **corrupted** tp2_2
...

Comment: Why is it invalid in C++? In the case of C++, the temporary objects are destructed as the last step of expression evaluation (meaning after the output). I've added a noisy destructor, compiled the code with `-O0` to eliminate any compiler optimizations and got the correct output with the destructors called after output happened. In the case of Python, I'm not sure about the rules, but they should be similar for sensible execution. (And the output with `-O0` is still incorrect)

Comment: You are right about the C++, the temporary persists for the lifetime of the bound reference, which is the expression statement in C++, but not in Python (see the updated answer).